# Flutter : How to add element to map field inside firebase database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find a way to add element to map field inside firebase database from my flutter code. The element as well is a map. So it's a nested map.

```
 Future updateImageDate({
        String token,
        int rating,
        int like,
        int display_count,
        //Map participants,
      }) async {
        return await pictureCollection.document(token).updateData({
          'rating': rating,
          'like': like,
          'display_count': display_count,
          //'participants': participants, 
         // I want to add only one element to this existing map field in firebase database.
         // Although currently it's empty, I want to keep add new element every time I use this method.
        // The element as well is a map. So it's a nested map.
         
        });
      }
```

Please help me! I'm looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you in advance. :D

Answer (score 0):

To write to a map, use dot (`.`) notation. So:

```
pictureCollection.document(token).updateData({ 'path.to.field': 'new value' });
```

Comment: Is this one of those situations where you have to use FieldPath because of the special meaning of `.`?

Comment: I don't think so. It seems to be to just be a nested field, hence the use of dots to address the field name.

Comment: I decided to nest a bunch of maps inside a list instead